# Create f:ajax based registration with a few forms so that each of them disappearing after step

Tags: ajax, forms, jsf, render, commandbutton

I'm trying to make registration with a few steps using JSF. Everything is based on f:ajax because page not have to be reloaded.

When i press "Show First Step" button the result appears. I'm pressing "SecondStep" button and second step appears. But when I press "ThirdStep" button everything disappears and I see no steps at all. There is no difference between "SecondStep" and "ThirdStep" buttons. I can't find out why this code doesn't work.

Here's html:

```
<aside class="block">
    <h:form id="newform"> 
        <h:commandButton value="Show First Step">
            <f:ajax event="action" render="-allContent -firstStepForm" listener="#{stateBean.ajaxShowFirstStep}"></f:ajax>
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:form>

    <h:panelGroup id="allContent">
        <h:panelGroup id="firstStep">
            <ui:fragment rendered="#{stateBean.firstStep}">
                <span>AAAA</span>
                <h:form id="firstStepForm">
                    <h:commandButton value="SecondStep">
                        <f:ajax event="action" render="-allContent  -secondStepForm" listener="#{stateBean.ajaxShowSecondStep}"></f:ajax>
                    </h:commandButton>
                </h:form>
            </ui:fragment>
        </h:panelGroup>

        <h:panelGroup id="secondStep">
            <ui:fragment rendered="#{stateBean.secondStep}">
                <span>BBBB</span>
                <h:form id="secondStepForm">
                    <h:commandButton value="ThirdStep">
                        <f:ajax event="action" render="-allContent  -thirdStepForm" listener="#{stateBean.ajaxShowThirdStep}"></f:ajax>
                    </h:commandButton>
                </h:form>
            </ui:fragment>
        </h:panelGroup>

        <h:panelGroup id="thirdStep">
            <ui:fragment rendered="#{stateBean.thirdStep}">
                <span>CCCC</span>
                <h:form id="thirdStepForm">
                    <h:commandButton value="Finish">
                        <f:ajax event="action" render="-allContent" listener="#{stateBean.ajaxShowFinish}"></f:ajax>
                    </h:commandButton>
                </h:form>
            </ui:fragment>
        </h:panelGroup>

        <h:panelGroup id="finish">
            <ui:fragment rendered="#{stateBean.finish}">
                <span>FINISH!!!</span>

            </ui:fragment>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:panelGroup>
</aside>
```

And here's bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "stateBean")
@ViewScoped
@Getter
@Setter
public class StateSavingBean implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 5264945113749405548L;

private Boolean firstStep;
private Boolean secondStep;
private Boolean thirdStep;
private Boolean finish;

public StateSavingBean() {

}

public void ajaxShowFirstStep(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    setFirstStep(true);
    setSecondStep(false);
    setThirdStep(false);
    setFinish(false);
}

public void ajaxShowSecondStep(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    setFirstStep(false);
    setSecondStep(true);
    setThirdStep(false);
    setFinish(false);
}

public void ajaxShowThirdStep(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    setFirstStep(false);
    setSecondStep(false);
    setThirdStep(true);
    setFinish(false);
}

public void ajaxShowFinish(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    setFirstStep(false);
    setSecondStep(false);
    setThirdStep(false);
    setFinish(true);
}

}
```

If I'll remove "-allContent" from render attribute of f:ajax I'd be able to pass all the steps till Finish, but previous and next steps will not be hidden.

Please help me find the solution.

I'm using:

Server: JBoss Application Server 7.1,

JSF: javax.faces-2.2.0-20130214.084242-247.jar

Faces Config:

```
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">
</faces-config>
```

Web Module: 3.0

Some answers:

1. Separator char was changed in web.xml:

   ```
   <context-param>
       <param-name>javax.faces.SEPARATOR_CHAR</param-name>
       <param-value>-</param-value>
   </context-param>
   ```
2. I tried without h:panelGroup id="allContent" and i was rendering only shown panelGroup that i want to hide and the next one I want to show. Result was the same.
3. I also was trying to use MyFaces 2.1.10, Mojarra 2.0.3-FCS and result was the same. BalusC wrote that it can be a bug that is fixed in JSF 2.2 but I still have this problem.

Hope someone will help me. Thank's!

Comment: I found no answers to my question. Maybe someone can share link to some documentation that can help me. Maybe I missed something in docs or didn't find it at all.